# knockoutjs passing value when using foreach inside of with binding throws reference error

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, referenceerror

I'm trying to dynamically create select inputs using knockoutjs.

My view looks like this -

```
<div data-bind="with: QuestionFilter">
  <form>
    <div>
      <select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'categoryID', value: selectedCategory">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: details">
      <select data-bind="options: subcategories, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'categoryID', value: selectedSubcategory">
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  ko.applyBindings({
    categories =  <?php echo json_encode($categories); ?>,        
    details = ko.observableArray([])       
  });
</script>
```

And my JS looks like this -

```
function QuestionFilter(categories, details) {
  var self = this;
  self.categories = ko.observableArray(categories);
  self.subcategories = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
  self.selectedSubcategory = ko.observable();
  self.superSubcategories = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(category) {
    function search(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].parentCategory_id === nameKey) {
          self.subcategories.push(myArray[i]);
        }
      }
    }   
    search(category, categories);
    details.push({ firstName: self.subcategories()});
  });

  self.selectedSubcategory.subscribe(function(subcategory) {
    function subsearch(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].parentCategory_id === nameKey) {
          self.superSubcategories.push(myArray[i]);
    }
      }
    }
   subsearch(subcategory, categories);
   details.push({ firstName: self.superSubcategories()});
  });
```

So, the variable `selectedCategory` will perform as expected and trigger the function in the `self.selectedCategory.subscribe`.  The variable `selectedSubcategory` will not perform as expected and will instead throw the following error - `ReferenceError: selectedSubcategory is not defined`.  I think it has something to do with using the `foreach` binding inside of a `with` binding, but I'm not sure.  Everything else works as expected, and I have even used this to add several objects to the details array successfully.

Any thoughts or clarification needed?

Comment: Your `ko.applyBindings` call doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: Hi Ismail, 
I've had to cut things down a bit so it fits nicely here.  I can guarantee you that it works, as everything in the code above works except for using the `selectedSubcategory.subscribe` bit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I wasn't accessing selectedSubcategory in the right context.  Prepending a `$parents[0].` gave the desired results.  So it looks like `$parents[0].selectedSubcategory`.  Strangely, `$parents` is supposed to provide the same context as `$parents[0]`, but it doesn't work in this case...